# Javascript code getElementByID with C# loop

Tags: javascript, draggable

I'm trying to use draggable HTML/JS on my code, but I get an issue when I try to loop over each element.
I don't overcome to convert my code from a single element to a `foreach` loop.

This is my code:

```
# CSS CODE
<style>
    #mydiv {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }

    #mydivheader {
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: move;
        z-index: 10;
        background-color: #2196F3;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>

# HTML CODE
<div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">
        Firstname Lastname
    </div>
</div>

# JAVASCRIPT CODE
<script>
    //Make the DIV element draggagle:
    dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

    function dragElement(elmnt) {
        var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
        if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
            /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
            document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
        } else {
            /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
            elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
        }

        function dragMouseDown(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();
            // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
            pos3 = e.clientX;
            pos4 = e.clientY;
            document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
            // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
            document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
        }

        function elementDrag(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();
            // calculate the new cursor position:
            pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
            pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
            pos3 = e.clientX;
            pos4 = e.clientY;
            // set the element's new position:
            elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
            elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
        }

        function closeDragElement() {
            /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
            document.onmouseup = null;
            document.onmousemove = null;
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works for one element like the example above.
But I would like to loop like this:

```
# HTML CODE
@foreach (var player in Model.PlayersToMatchs)
{
    <div id="mydiv@(player.Player.PlayerID)">
        <div id=" mydivheader@(player.Player.PlayerID)">
            @player.Player.Firstname @player.Player.Lastname
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I tried to modify my Javascript part by changing the first line to take into account the partial `id`:

```
dragElement(document.querySelector('[id^="mydiv"]').id);
```

But How I can rewrite this part:

```
function dragElement(elmnt) {
        var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
        if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
            /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
            document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
        } else {
            /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
            elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
        }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Have you considered calling the `dragElement` function for all the elements you created using a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @RafaelDuarte I assume that not. My goal is to take each element and be able to drag each one independantly to the others

Comment: `querySelector` returns the first element that matches the selector given, so you're not saving yourself there. You need to rethink your approach to have another function that gets called with a list of elements (I suggest using a class rather than partial matching on ID); have that function call `dragElement` in a loop of the elements that have the class.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4kb3xtq/1/)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Heretic Monkey said, querySelector only returns the first element, you need to use `querySelectorAll` to get all elements and then loop the elements array to call the `dragElement` function.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="mydiv"]');
elements.forEach(element=> {
   dragElement(element);
   }
);
```